# Validating Objects in Spring REST

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring REST web service in java, that can be used by Android/IPhone.
My method in the controller is following

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/registerUser")
    public ModelAndView registerUser(@RequestBody User user,HttpServletRequest request){

//register user

}
```

I have an idea about **Form based validations** with Spring validators that are most-closely work with **ModelAttribute** in case of Spring Websites.

My question is that, How can i validate the **user** object, and send the specific error to **Android**/Iphone end? Say if username is not in email pattern , how can i send the error message specific to wrong username to Mobile ends, and how will they display that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at the JSR303 annotation driven bean validation stuff.  This link will get you started:

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

And also:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/

There are also plenty of tutorials out there too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But,i am looking for Spring's own validators for validation purpose. However, i will look the stuff that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Now , i am able to validate the objects with JSR validations. Cheers...:)